# Is there a way to print the value of history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue app. I am trying to the the value of the previous visited page using  history.go(-1) and based on that value I have to assign values to a variable.

Something like this:

```
<script>
 created: function() {
  var str = history.go(-1)
  if (str.includes("/users/")) {
   console.log("Value present");    
  }
  else {
   console.log("Not Present");
  }
 }
</script>
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work for me.

Comment: why dont' you use `document.referrer`?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work because accessing one's history is a huge security issue.

We often forget when we write JavaScript it executes on someone else's computer.

That said if the person is navigating within your site there are couple things you could do though.

You can create you own history state and save it to localstorage so when user changes page or leaves you can know next time where was he/she left off

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it?